# Setting SecurityContextHolder.setContext(...) to a mock carries across to different test classes even with @DirtiesContext

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-test

In one of my test classes, I use:

```
//Make a security context
SecurityContext securityContext = mock( SecurityContext.class );
SecurityContextHolder.setContext( securityContext );
```

And then I set some things on it.

In another test class, I get a failure due to that mock still being in there. I added `@DirtiesContext` on all of the test classes but it still happens. When I check the class of the security context in the 2nd class, it says it's a mock.

How do I properly reset everything between classes?

The first class is run as:

```
@RunWith( SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class )
@SpringBootTest(
    webEnvironment = SpringBootTest.WebEnvironment.RANDOM_PORT
)
@DirtiesContext
```

And the second is just:

```
@RunWith( SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class )
@DirtiesContext
```

Comment: Does `@DirtiesContext` with class mode - `AFTER_EACH_TEST_METHOD` do the same thing?

Comment: In the test after the test you need to clear the context. `SecurityContextHolder.clearContext`. Say in an `@After` or `@AfterClass` method (depending on where you set it). `@DirtiesContext` won't help here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The word "context" is confusing you.

Those are two very different "contexts".

`@DirtiesContext` is related to the test `ApplicationContext`; whereas, the `SecurityContext` is part of Spring Security and had nothing to do with the `ApplicationContext`.

Thus, if you set a `SecurityContext` in Spring Security's `SecurityContextHolder`, it is your job to remove it once your test completes.

The latter requires manual work on your part. If you want Spring Security's testing support to take care of everything, you'll likely be happier with `@WithMockUser` and related testing support in `spring-security-test`.

Comment: Sure. Spring Security testing support: https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/5.0.4.RELEASE/reference/htmlsingle/#test-method

Comment: Spring testing support: https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/5.0.6.RELEASE/spring-framework-reference/testing.html#dirtiescontext

Comment: I meant examples for security context

Comment: Well, you already know how to set the `SecurityContext`, since you posted that code in your question. So, all you have to do is invoke `SecurityContextHolder.clearContext()` _after_ your test completes (e.g., in an `@After` method in JUnit 4).